# sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant ignoring the instanceurl param

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, jwt

I'm having troubles authenticating to my Dev Hub Org using the JWT token. The command:

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid *** --username *** --jwtkeyfile *** --setdefaultdevhubusername --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com
```

results in:

```
ERROR:  This org appears to have a problem with its OAuth configuration. 
Reason: invalid_grant - expired authorization code
username: ***,
clientId: ***,
loginUrl: <Not Specified>,
privateKey: ***.
```

I'm curious about the `Not specified` value for the loginUrl.

If it try to run the auth command in the context of a configured sfdx project, that has the default login url set to `test.salesforce.org`, this URL appears as the `loginUrl` and the authentication also fails (as I'm trying to login to a Dev Hub Org).

It seems that the `--instanceurl` doesn't in fact override the login URL as documented? Or am I missing something here?

My `sfdx` version is:

```
sfdx-cli/6.25.0 (linux-x64) node-v8.11.3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this myself, but I still believe there is a small bug in SFDX CLI that steered me off my course when debugging this.

The root cause turned out to be an incorrect system time set on the server I was running the `auth:jwt:grant` from - hence the `expired authorization code`, as the requests were coming "from the past".

But, the error detail message is incorrect when it comes to the `loginUrl` parameter - it doesn't seem to notice the `--instanceurl` option passed to the command. The command itself runs fine and targets correct instance, it's just the error message that has a different `loginUrl` that was actually used. And that made me spend quite some time wondering about the instance URLs rather than the JWT flow and grants.