# invalid_grant: expired authorization code when using OAuth2 flow

Tags: oauth2, authentication, oauth, authorization

I am using OAuth2 to authorize the user I generate the URL at the backend send the url to the frontend (which is in VUE ) which open it in the new window the callback url is one of the route of the frontend which collect the Code from the query param and send it to the Backend but when I Authorize it in the Backend it give error that code is expired I am attaching my code sample for your reference . I will be highly thankful for the help

```
const oauth2 = new jsforce.OAuth2({
clientId: salesforceCredentials.clientId,
clientSecret: salesforceCredentials.clientSecret,
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/salesforceAuth',
});
/**

To get teh Authorization credetials for Salesforce
@param {*} req
@param {*} res
*/
async function getAuthorizationInfo(req, res) {
const conn =
new jsforce.Connection({ oauth2: oauth2 });
const code = req.query.code;
console.log(code)
//console.log(req)
conn.authorize(code, function (err, userInfo) {
if (err) {
console.log("hello word")
return console.error(err);
}
console.log("hello word2")
// Now you can get the access token, refresh token, and instance URL information.
// Save them to establish connection next time.
console.log(userInfo.state)
console.log(conn.accessToken);
console.log(conn.refreshToken);
console.log(conn.instanceUrl);
//console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);
//console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);
// ...
res.send('success'); // or your desired response
});
}
//
// Get authorization url and redirect to it.
//
router.get('/salesforce/oAuth2', function (req, res) {
res.send(oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl({ scope: 'api' }));
});
router.get('/salesforce/oAuth2Response', getAuthorizationInfo)
```

Comment: User name and password is also required to get the token.

Comment: @YsrShk as I am using OAuth 2.0 we don't require username password

Comment: https://jsforce.github.io/document/#connection

Comment: Did you find any solution to this, I'm running into the same issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue using simple_salesforce package trying JWT token authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, this question has been answered here (set correct time on your server):
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/226430/90715